# Golang Reflection Improvement

Tags: reflection, go

Anyone know a better way to do this?
The goal is for a custom defined Field to be casted back again from a string to its int type.

```
switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int:
            intID, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 0)
            if err != nil {
                    return err
            }
            val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(int(intID)))

    case reflect.Int8:
            intID, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 8)
            if err != nil {
                    return err
            }
            val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(int8(intID)))

    case reflect.Int16:
            intID, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 16)
            if err != nil {
                    return err
            }
            val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(int16(intID)))

    case reflect.Int32:
            intID, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 32)
            if err != nil {
                    return err
            }
            val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(int32(intID)))

    case reflect.Int64:
            intID, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 64)
            if err != nil {
                    return err
            }
            val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(intID))
   }
```

Comment: Is the `id` always a positive number?

Comment: no, but its always an integer. I skipped the Uint cases for stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Value.SetInt` / `Value.SetUint`:

```
func setId(id string, v interface{}) {
    // error checking is left as an exercise
    val := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem() // this will panic if v isn't a pointer
    switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        idn, _ := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 64)
        if val.OverflowInt(idn) {
            // handle large values
        }
        val.SetInt(idn)
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
        idn, _ := strconv.ParseUint(id, 10, 64)
        if val.OverflowUint(idn) {
            // handle large values
        }
        val.SetUint(idn)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2gS4hQ-T-K)</kbd>

Comment: @sharpner check the updated version, my original version had a bug handling larger negative values.